# Custom web-notification sound in Chrome on Android

Tags: javascript, android, mobile-chrome, web-notifications

Is it possible to set custom web-notification sound in mobile Chrome on Android (using javascript from service-worker)?

And if so, are there any restrictions to this (file type, size, sound length)?

Thanks

Comment: You should try to reproduce a sound inside the push event, but I haven't tested it. I think that the best solution would be to have a sound effect in the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/notification) - but that is something that must be considered by those who write the spec.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `sound` option defined in the [standard](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-serviceworkerregistration-shownotificationtitle-options).

However no browser support it at the moment (just tested on Chrome 58).

**2022 Update**: I can no longer see it in the standard, so it was probably removed completely.